# Google API display distance point A and B

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am currently using PHP (CodeIgniter) and tring to display distance beatween two city in my index page where are the all posts
For example in every post it should display distance beatween city (New York - Boston 4587 mile 14h:59min) something like this 
What is the best and easiest way to do that.
Thank you for answering :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link you can go through

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html

Even if you don't use their API, their PHP and SQL query solves most of the problem.